# Javascript get url and redirect by adding to it

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a situation where I need to get the current page url and redirect to a new page by adding to the current page url. For example:

http://www.mywebsite.com/page1/page2

needs to redirect to:

http://www.mywebsite.com/page1/page2/page3

I need it to be relative because "/page1/page2/" will always be different, but "page3" will always be the same.

I've tried: location.href = "./page3"; but that does not work. The result is:
http://www.mywebsite.com/page1/page3

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?:

```
location.href = location.pathname + "/page3";
```

Answer (score 0):

Get and Set URL using either `window.location.href` or `document.URL;`

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "/page3";
```

Should do what you're looking for.

Comment: This will include QueryStrings, hashes, etc.. E.g. `http://www.mywebsite.com/page1/page2?id=5` =>  `http://www.mywebsite.com/page1/page2?id=5/page3`